# How do I properly start a vnc server on fedora?

Tags: ssh, fedora, firewall, vnc

I don't remember this being difficult last time I used vnc. This is what I've tried (I'm running fedora 21)...

First off, install a vnc server.

```
sudo yum install tigervnc-server
... y
```

Now to unblock the port. Not sure if `vnc-server` is correct here, but [this page](https://stufs4u.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/install-and-configure-vnc-server-in-fedora-20/) says it is. BTW, I initially tried `firewall-config`, but for the life of me couldn't get it to work via SSH with X forwarding.

```
> sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service vnc-server
> sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
# vnc-server not listed. damn. maybe if I try again, but pressing the keys harder
> sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service vnc-server
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: vnc-server
# ...? whatever...
> sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5900/tcp
# the port's there, that should do
```

I can understand why many give up and `sudo service firewalld stop` as a last resort.
Now to run the vnc server,

```
> vncpasswd
Password: *
Verify: *
> vncserver
# seems to have started
```

Connecting remotely doesn't work. Even connecting locally doesn't work (`unable connect to socket: Connection refused (111)`, although despite *refused* it's the same message when no server is running, so it probably meant something a little less like it found something to talk to in the first place).

For the moment I don't care about setting up a service to have the server start automatically. How do I do the basics?

[*EDIT*]
To connect I was simply typing the hostname into RealVNC Viewer on windows or running `vncviewer localhost` to test connecting locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, unlike some windows vnc servers I've used where the server shares the one desktop, there can be many virtual X desktops. Rather than have a single server that manages multiple desktops, there are multiple servers which each use a different port.

- Port 5900 (`:0`) - local screen/login (not sure of correct terminology here)
- Port 5901 (`:1`) - virtual desktop 1
- Port 5902 (`:2`) - virtual desktop 2
- ...

I guess a shorthand or maybe user friendly way to connect to these is adding the `:0` or `:1` etc. to the host name you're connecting to. This adds a number to the port before connecting.

Now without any arguments to `vncserver`, the default is to start a virtual display `:1` (on port 5901) and by default `vncviewer` connects to 5900, which explains why I couldn't connect.
 A program such as `x11vnc` can share the main `:0` desktop (e.g. `x11vnc -ncache 10 -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -display :0`), but tigrevnc complains if you try `vncserver :0`.

**TLDR:**
I should have connected to display 1 or used port 5901:

```
vncviewer localhost:1
vncviewer localhost::5901
```